# Почему h:dataTable в JSF не работает с Set<Entry.Map>?

Tags: java, jsf

Есть следующий код бина:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@ManagedBean(name = "test", eager = true)
public class TestBean {

    public Map<String, Integer> getMap() {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("one", 1);
        map.put("two", 2);
        map.put("three", 3);
        return map;
    }
}
```

И страница, которая его использует

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:dataTable value="#{test.map.entrySet}" var="o">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Key</f:facet>
                #{o.key}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Value</f:facet>
                #{o.value}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

В результате генерируется следующая страница

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><body><table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Key</th>
<th scope="col">Value</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Вопрос в том почему он не видит значения, которые лежат в ключе и значение  объекта Entry? Я знаю что этот тег не работает с картами, но здесь то используется коллекция. Все это запускалось на Tomcat 8 c библиотеками com.sun.faces.jsf-api и com.sun.faces.jsf-impl версии 2.2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так работает?

```
<h:dataTable value="#{test.map.entrySet()}" var="o">
```

entrySet - это не свойство. Нужно скобки нарисовать.
Без скобок пытается найти метод getEntrySet() (`map.getEntrySet()`) или ключ "entrySet" (`map.get("entrySet")`). И не находит почему-то.